# Stop PhpStorm from adding a new line after function declaration when arguments split across multiple lines

Tags: coding-style, phpstorm

In my PhpStorm 8.0.3 code style, I have set it to add a new line after a function declaration, which works fine.

Problem is now I'm in a new project that follows the [PSR-2 Standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md), which say that the opening brace of a function MUST be placed in the same line that the closing parenthesis of the function arguments when these split across multiple lines, as you can see [here](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#44-method-arguments).

I want this when arguments split across multiple lines...

```
public function myMethod(
    MyClass $arg1,
    $arg2 = null
) {
    // method body
}
```

...and this when they are all in the same line...

```
public function myMethod(MyClass $arg1, $arg2 = null)
{
    // method body
}
```

I was trying to search for that option but I couldn't find it - I know I can decide whether I want to add the new line for **all** functions, but I need it only in these particular occasions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the `File -> Settings` dialogue, under `Editor -> Code Style -> PHP` select `Wrapping and Braces` tab on the right hand side.

Find the `Function declaration parameters` block and check the main control, here you have a bunch of options regarding wrapping parameters and few other options in this block to control braces placement. Also look at the `Braces placement` block above.

Answer (score 17):

As a complement to @marekful's answer. To make it clearer, these are the 2 settings needed to achieve what I wanted:

[image]