# PhpStorm properly format func decl with params on multiple lines and return type

Tags: phpstorm

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805484/stop-phpstorm-from-adding-a-new-line-after-function-declaration-when-arguments-s). I want PhpStorm to properly (according to PSR-2) format function declaration when arguments split across multiple lines. It do when I don't specify return type

```
public function trafficFromStartDate(
    string $startDate,
    string $id
) {
    ...
}
```

But when I specify return type it break `{` on next line, but it should keep it on the same line where `)`

```
public function trafficFromStartDate(
    string $startDate,
    string $id
) : stdClass
{
    ...
}
```

I need

```
public function trafficFromStartDate(
    string $startDate,
    string $id
) : stdClass {
    ...
}
```

My format config

[image: format config]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to have formatting like that in current PhpStorm versions (2016.2 is the latest).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31618 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.